# Why am I getting NullPointerException in `getResources().getStringArray()` while the Activity is already created?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-resources, android-context

Why am I getting an NPE, when the `Activity` is already created/`context` is already initialized?

**EXPLAINED:**

I am inside a fragment's `onActivityCreated` method, which ensures the the `Activity` is already created, and thus the `context` is already initialized. I get the application resources like:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Resources appResources = getActivity().getResources();
        Log.i(TAG, "APPRESOURCES >>> " + appResources.toString());//check
        ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter expandableRecyclerView = new ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), populateList(appResources));
        ...
    }
```

The `Log.i` statement above prints

```
APPRESOURCES >>> android.content.res.Resources@45fbef68
```

---

Inside the `populateList(appResources)` method called above, I create an object of `MyParentObject` and pass the `appResources` to its constructor:

```
private List<ParentObject> populateList(Resources appResources) {
        ...
        MyParentObject myParentObject = new MyParentObject(appResources);
        ...
}
```

---

In the `MyParentObject` class,

```
public class MyParentObject implements ParentObject {   
        Resources appResources;     
        ...
        public MyParentObject(Resources appResources) {         
            this.appResources = appResources;   
        }
        ...    
        private String [] spinnerFields = appResources.getStringArray(R.array.spinnerFields_arrayResource);//******ERROR********
        ...  
    }
```

**The statement which assigns `spinnerFields` is where I get the NPE.**

---

***NOTE: Initially, I was passing around a `context` object obtained from `getActivity()` in `onActivityCreated()` of the fragment. But during the process of debugging for this NPE, I changed to passing around the `appResources` object.***

Comment: on which line are you getting the crash ?

Comment: java's basics ... what goes first? constructor or field initializer? http://ideone.com/vLmnVW

Comment: @Blackbelt In the last snippet, the last statement! The one which assigns `spinnerFields`. I added `//********ERROR***************` to it.

Comment: nice catch @Selvin..

Comment: @Selvin I am learning Java as well, but I am in a situation where I have no option but write this app I am working on. So I am reading and practicing and implementing things.

Comment: @Selvin Thank you. Problem solved. If you can post an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please tell me the reason of the downvote, so that I can improve.

Comment: did I answered? no .... you did it ...i just give you a hint ... so write the answer by yourself :)

Comment: @Selvin Thanks, just posted an answer =)

Answer (score 0):

The credit of this solution goes to Selvin's comment. The field has to be declared before the constructor, and then I initialized it inside the constructor, like so:

```
public class MyParentObject implements ParentObject {   
        private String [] spinnerFields;     
        ...
        public MyParentObject(Resources appResources) {         
            spinnerFields = appResources.getStringArray(R.array.spinnerFields_arrayResource);   
        }
        ...     
}
```